# Compiling i386 binaries on amd64 Debian?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, debian, wine

I'm trying to build [fsthost](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsthost/) on 64-bit Debian Stable and the last (linking) step fails:

```
m@debian:~/Downloads/fsthost-1.5.4$ make
winegcc -m32 -o fsthost32 amc_32.o jackamc_32.o fst_32.o gtk_32.o jackvst_32.o \
    jfst_32.o fxb_32.o fps_32.o vstwin_32.o cpuusage_32.o info_32.o \
    midifilter_32.o list_32.o -m32 -mwindows -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine \
    -lpthread -lX11 -ljack -lxml2 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 \
    -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo \
    -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
winegcc: gcc failed
make: *** [fsthost32] Error 2
m@debian:~/Downloads/fsthost-1.5.4$
```

Notice, that `winegcc` is being used here, not `gcc`.

So, `ld` claims there's no `libX11.so`, let's check it:

```
m@debian:~$ locate libX11.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
m@debian:~$
```

Bingo! There's no `/usr/lib/***i386***-linux-gnu/libX11.***so***`! When I manually add a symlink from `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so` to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6`, the line:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

obviously **disappears** from `ld`'s output.

Why are there no `*.so` symlinks in `i386-linux-gnu` directory and how should I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to overcome this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @sudoman, if I remember correctly, I built it in a 32-bit chroot. But later moved to a saner distro → NixOS. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the shared libraries but are missing the *.so symlinks that seems to indicate that you have installed the runtime library package but not the dev library package.  What was the name of the package that you installed to create the `i386-linux-gnu` directory?  I'd search for related packages that have 'dev' or similar in the name and try installing them.

Just a guess here, but the package you may be missing is [ia32-libs-dev](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ia32-libs-dev)

Comment: I did install all the `-dev:i386` versions. :( After suggestion on #debian @ Freenode, I set up an i386 chroot to compile the app. Works now. :) Thank you!